# What is the definition of a "maximal feasible solution" in a 0/1 knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I have the following $0/1$ knapsack problem
\begin{aligned}
&z=\max \left\{p^T x=12 x_{1}+8 x_{2}+17 x_{3}+11 x_{4}+6 x_{5}+2 x_{6}+2 x_{7}\right\} \\
&\text { s.t. } \quad a^T x=4 x_{1}+3 x_{2}+7 x_{3}+5 x_{4}+3 x_{5}+2 x_{6}+3 x_{7} \leq 9 \\
&\quad x \in\{0,1\}^{7}
\end{aligned}

and I was told to give examples of a maximal feasible solution with the maximum cardinality and a maximal feasible solution with the smallest cardinality. I assume the cardinality is about the number of $x_i$ I choose to be equal to $1$, but what does the maximal refer to? Is it about having an optimal value in the objective function? If so, why not just say one of the optimal solutions instead?

Comment: If you're correct about what cardinality means, maybe "maximal" means: for the maximum cardinality possible for a feasible solution, find the feasible solution with that cardinality that has the maximum value. That might not be an optimal solution to the problem, since there might not be an optimal solution with that cardinality.

Comment: This seems like a question you should ask the person who gave you the assignment. If it's a problem in a book, perhaps the book makes it clear, even if not spelled out in the problem.

Comment: I suspect "maximal feasible solution" here is intended to mean "optimal solution", so that the question is asking for optimal solutions with the most and fewest ones.

Answer (score 2):

"Maximal feasible" means that the solution is feasible and if you change any $x_i$ from $0$ to $1$, the solution is no longer feasible.

See section 4.3 of [this paper](http://alexandria.tue.nl/openaccess/Metis196442.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this is the intended meaning -- if it were, "maximal feasible solution with the maximum cardinality" would also maximize redundancy. :-)

Comment: Hmm, what I described is the usual definition of *maximal* (cannot be increased without destroying the property).  Under that definition, the maximal feasible solutions do not all have the same cardinality or objective value.

Comment: To clarify, I'm thinking of maximal with respect to set inclusion (independent of the objective value).  But I agree with @MarkL.Stone that whoever gave the assignment probably also gave a definition of *maximal*.

Comment: I agree with "maximal" *usually* meaning maximal cardinality, and you're right, it could mean "no space to flip another variable" irrespective of objective value. It would make the existence of an objective function irrelevant to the question, but that's not beyond the bounds of possibility.